# How do I call ngAfterViewInit() if specific condition is met

Tags: angular, mat-pagination

Here is the reference code [URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-pagination-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsimple-mat-table%2Fsimple-mat-table.component.html)

so I have using the above code in my component.... but in my comonent table is inside ngcontainer which gets visible once some flag(e.g. visibleTabulardata) is set to true

```
<ng-container *ngIf='visibleTabulardata'> <!-- this gets visible after some specific condition
inside this table and mat-paginator code is used from the above URL
</ng-container>
```

Now they have used below code to initialize data across pages

```
 @ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild('paginatorPageSize') paginatorPageSize: MatPaginator;

  pageSizes = [3, 5, 7];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSourceWithPageSize.paginator = this.paginatorPageSize;
  }
```

So and in my ts file one method is there which sets visibleTabulardata as true

```
enableTableData(){
this.visibleTabulardata =true;
}
```

I tried calling ngAfterViewInit() nside enableTableData() but it is not working

Comment: Is this visibleTabulardata happening after some backend API ?

Comment: no this is boolean variable in TS file which I am enabling by button clicking... enableTableData()  is the function which sets it to true

Comment: easy workaround would be using [hidden] instead of ngIf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding

```
<div  [hidden]="visibleTabulardata">
```

Based on a button click you hide/show the tabel and pagination.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-pagination-example-yhyftk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsimple-mat-table%2Fsimple-mat-table.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fsimple-mat-table%2Fsimple-mat-table.component.html&file=src%2Fapp%2Fsimple-mat-table%2Fsimple-mat-table.component.html

Comment: See I checked your code and tried the same but here one issue comes.... so when you hide the table and again unhide it then its showFirstLastButtons gets disabled and do not work again.....

Comment: What do you mean? Im clicking the button several times and table hide and unhide ...

Comment: yes but the next and previous page buttons.... they are non clickable after hide and unhide operation

Comment: <div [hidden]="visibleTabulardata">

Comment: actually I think mat paginator is reinitalized and hence for first call of onclick show button matpaginator is returned as undefined

Comment: check the code has updated. paginater and all is working ok.

Answer (score 1):

`ngAfterViewInit()` is an Angular [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) and is not supposed to be called arbitrarily. The best way in your case is to move these assignments to a separate method and call this method from your hook and from `enableTableData()`

Comment: its not working

Comment: @John Be aware that ngAfterViewInit is triggered after ngOnInit() so whatever you are trying to assign has to be properly bound to be reflected where you want. To know what is potentially not working you will have to provide more code.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call ngAfterViewInit by yourself as it's a life cycle hook triggered by angular itself. instead, make a method initPaginator and encapsulate paginator code in that call initPaginator where you want

```
initPaginator(){
 this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
 this.dataSourceWithPageSize.paginator = this.paginatorPageSize; }
```

Comment: Hi tried this as well but its not working